# Showing that $A^n/M^n \cong (A/M)^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am just trying to show that for $M$ a maximal ideal we have an isomorphism of $A$-modules $A^n / M^n \cong (A / M)^n$.

I wanted to make sure that I have correctly understood the concepts and what the elements in these modules look like:

$(A / M)^n$ would have elements of the form: $(a_{i_1} + M) +\cdots+(a_{i_n} + M) $

and $A^n / M^n$ would have elements of the form: $[a_{i_1}e_{1}+a_{i_2}e_{2}+\cdots+a_{i_n}e_{n} ] + [(M_1) +\cdots+(M_n)]$

where $e_{i}$ are the multiplicative identity elements of the ith copy of $A$.

Then a simple isomorphism that seems natural is just mapping $(a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n}) $ to $[a_{i_1}e_{1}+a_{i_2}e_{2}+...+a_{i_n}e_{n} ]$, which would clearly be surjective.

It would also be injective since the zero of $(A / M)^n$ would just be the $a_i \in M$, which also characterises the zero element in $(A^n / M^n)$. And this is the only class of elements which is sent to $0$ of $(A^n / M^n)$

Have I understood what the elements of these modules look like, and have I got the right idea about how to show that these are indeed isomorphic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true in a much more general setting; let $R$ be a ring (commutative or not is irrelevant) and $M$ a (left) $R$-module, with a submodule $L$. Then, for each positive integer $n$,
$$
(M/L)^n\cong M^n/L^n
$$
To prove this, consider the canonical projection $\pi\colon M\to M/L$ and define $f\colon M^n\to (M/L)^n$ by
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=(\pi(x_1),\pi(x_2),\dots,\pi(x_n))
$$
this is clearly a surjective homomorphism and
$$
\ker f=L^n
$$

Comment: Ahh thanks. I like this. It's a much 'cleaner' way to do it. Though, the way I have done it - is there anything fundamentally incorrect about it? Just wanted to know if I am understanding these things correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @K.Easley Not really, although the notation $[a_{i_1}e_{1}+a_{i_2}e_{2}+\cdots+a_{i_n}e_{n} ] + [(M_1) +\cdots+(M_n)]$ doesn't seem good. However, defining maps using representatives of cosets needs showing the definition only depends on the coset. Using the homomorphism theorem is easier, generally.